# Error: Object #<Object> has no method 'toUpperCase'

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm currently getting the error `Object #<Object> has no method 'toUpperCase'` before the POST request is made, so I would like and appreciate a lot your help! Thanks

```
function ajaxeo(url, data, method){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: method,
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}

function cambio(ID, newValue){
ajaxeo("includes/php/ajax/changeProvider.php?oldID="+ID, "post", {"newVal": newValue});
}

var editable = $('div[contentEditable][dataAjax]');
for (var i=0, len = editable.length; i<len; i++){
    editable[i].setAttribute('data-orig',editable[i].innerHTML);
    editable[i].onblur = function(){
        if (this.innerHTML == $(this).attr('data-orig')) {
            // no change
        }
        else {
            // change has happened, store new value
            $(this).attr('data-orig', $(this).html())
            cambio($(this).attr('dataId'), $(this).html());
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed your parameters wrong

```
ajaxeo("includes/php/ajax/changeProvider.php?oldID="+ID, "post", {"newVal": newValue});
```

should be

```
ajaxeo("includes/php/ajax/changeProvider.php?oldID="+ID, {"newVal": newValue}, "post");
```

The error is probably jQuery trying to make sure the method is in uppercase

Comment: Thanks! I should noticed it :B